# how to write a regular expression in PHP if statment

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am writing a chat bot in PHP.

here is a part of the code

```
public function messageReceived($from, $message){
        $message = trim($message);

                if(stristr($message,"hi")|| stristr($message,"heylo")||stristr($message,"hello")||stristr($message,"yo")||stristr($message,"bonjour")){
            return "Hello,$from,how are you"; // help section
        }
```

now in the if statement ,can i use a regular expression such that if the message starts with :
H or Y it will return the given statement.

something of sort:

H* || Y* in formal languages

is there any such way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(preg_match('/^(?:hi|hey|hello) (.+)/i', $str, $matches)) {
    echo 'Hello ' . $matches[1];
}
```

Explanation:

```
/ # beginning delimiter
  ^ # match only at the beginning of the string
  ( # new group
    ?: # do not capture the group contents
    hi|hey|hello # match one of the strings
  )
  ( # new group
    . # any character
      + # 1..n times
    )
/ # ending delimiter
  i # flag: case insensitive
```

Comment: thanks just one more thing if i have to search the same keyword inside a string ,let's suppose if to search hior hello in a string:
preg_match('/(.+)(?:hi|hey|hello) (.+)/i  is this correct?

Comment: No, simply remove the `^` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks :) was of great help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to check for an *H* or *Y* (case insensitive) at the start of the message

```
preg_match('/^H|Y/i', $message)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_match for this:

```
if (preg_match('/^(H|Y).*/', $message)) {
    // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just get the first letter with `$message[0]`.

Comment: that'll be specific i am going to use it further , accessing through index won't help in those cases

Comment: so can you give some examples of things you want to do in the future. Maybe I can correct my answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are certain that you want to compare the first letter, you can do that without using regex.

```
    if( substr($message, 0, 1) =='H' || substr($message, 0, 1) == 'Y' ){
        //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entire function will look like this:

```
public function messageReceived($from, $message){

  $message = trim($message);

  if(preg_match('/^H|Y/i', $message){

     return "Hello $from, how are you"; // help section

  }
  else {
     // check for other conditions
  }
}
```